# email forwarding removes original sender's email address in Google app scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-api

Here's my Google App Script code:

```
var messages = threads[x].getMessages();
for (var y in messages) 
{
  messages[y].forward("someone@example.com");
}
```

This forwards fine, but it resets the `from` field of message to the email id of account which executes the script. This removes all credentials of the original sender of `message`. How to forward the email more elegantly such that all original headers (at least `from` and `to`) are retained? If the original message was sent to a *list of people* or a *newsgroup*, I need to retain it in the forwarded message.

Answer (score 0):

In general a forwarded email does not retain the original from and to address. If you forward an email using GMail or Outlook you'll notice this. The GMailApp is behaving the same way.

Comment: Yes, but atleast it appends a nice `--Forwarded message--` details before the message body. Moreover, if you enable forwarding in gmail, you'll see the forwarded email natively retains original from and to addresses. It looks as if the message is sent directly to this email.