# Google Apps Script forward() method has a different result than with UI

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, gmail-api

[Google Apps Message documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message#forwardrecipient) shows how to use .forward() method, however the result is quite different to the UI.

The forwarded email does not contain any of the header information in the body, eg

> ```
> ​---------- Forwarded message ----------
> From: John Smith <john_smith@gmail.com>
> Date: 10 April 2018 at 19:47
> Subject: test email
> To: Mr Me <me@gmail.com>
> ```

You also don't get your signature - but I don't really care about that.

Rather it just appears that the exact original email is now coming from you.

So for example, if I get an email with a message "Jane is dull" from John, and I forward to Jane, she would see that it was John who sent it.  However using an app script .forward() method, she would think that I wrote it.

How can I make forward actually replicate forward with context and meaning, other than reading the original message and creating a completely new message?

Comment: I think you're going to have to create your own function to do "forwarding" in the manner you want. You might consult Apps Script / Gmail issue trackers and raise awareness as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a known functionality as what specified in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10876644/email-forwarding-removes-original-senders-email-address-in-google-app-scripts). Also, this functionality was supported by another [post from StackExchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/106092/gmail-loses-original-from-address-when-forwarding-an-email) using the Gmail App. But upon checking [this](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/16434/forwarding-as-attachment-instead-of-inline-using-the-gmail-web-client), you can actually keep the original "From" details when forwarding using the send as attachment option as specified in the post.

Comment: Thanks, however I think that's all to do with web GUI version.  I have a script, which when forwarding doesn't include the nice "forwarded message" section, which is what the system I am forwarding to uses to attach the message to relevant contacts and accounts.  I just want the app scripts .forward() to do what the GUI does now.

Answer (score 0):

Running into this issue where message.getPlainBody() does not actually return the text contents of the message.
Now if I forward the message from web GUI and call getPlainBody(), it works fine, all text content is returned.
If I call message.forward('whatever') from script before calling getPlainBody() on forwarded message, the output is missing relevant text as well, as if I do it on the original message.

Essentially it looks like an issue with getPlainBody() method on messages. Doesn't extract all text content.